# Get system colors from KDE

Tags: c++, c, qt

Let say that I'm writing console application in pure C/C++ and want to get system colors from KDE (don't ask why :P ). This is not Qt application.

I know how to do this on windows:

- load user32.dll
- call GetSysColor function

and on linux GTK based:

- load libgtk-x11-2.0.so
- create dummy window gtk_window_new
- get style gtk_widget_get_style from window
- read colors: gtk_widget_get_style.dark[0].green

But can't figure out how do this on KDE. Which Qt lib should I load and which function to call?

Comment: it depends, if your linux distribution is using X11 you can use xlib to do that.

Comment: What are "system colors"?

Comment: Theme colors (for text selection, button background etc)

Comment: it depends on what you want to do and from what kind of information you are starting, for example there is `XGetImage` that is often used to take a dump of the single pixels.

Comment: No, I can't base on pixels. I need to get button face color, edit background color etc. So I need to use Qt libs for that